# binary search recursive returns none

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, return

I was trying to write binary search in python. What i write is :

```
arr = [6, 13, 14, 25, 33, 43, 51, 53, 64, 72, 84, 93, 95, 96, 97]

def binarySearch(arr, low, high, key):
    if(low <= high):
        mid = (low + high) // 2
        if(arr[mid] == key):
            return key

        elif(arr[mid] > key):
            binarySearch(arr, low, mid - 1, key)

        else:
            binarySearch(arr, mid + 1, high, key)

    else:
        return -1

i = binarySearch(arr, 0, len(arr) - 1, 33)
print(i)
```

It returns None. Then i discovered that i did not put return statements at the beginning of recursive calls. But in my head, without return statements, it should return the key anyway, because first it controls if it matches with key. Why function keep executing after finding the key and returns None instead of key.

Comment: what you actually wanna do is RETURN THE FUNCTION for example do `return binarySearch(arguments)` and not simple `binarySearch()`

Answer (score 0):

It does not return because you are not asking it to. However, I am guessing that if you DID put the return statements in, it would still return the wrong thing - the key, vs the index where key is situated (you know what key is, why would you want to do a computation to return it?)

Comment: Yes i should return index of key. That was my bad to not fix it. I mean my point is, should not it terminate the function when ---
        if(arr[mid] == key):
            return key
---
This line is executed ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non-recursive variation of binary search that you might consider.

```
def binary_search(arr, x):
    # Time O(log n)
    # Space O(1)
    left = 0; right = len(arr) - 1
    while left <= right:
        mid = (left + right) // 2
        if x > arr[mid]:
            left = mid + 1
        elif x < arr[mid]:
            right = mid - 1
        else:
            return mid
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [6, 13, 14, 25, 33, 43, 51, 53, 64, 72, 84, 93, 95, 96, 97]


def binarySearch(arr, low, high, key):
    if(low <= high):
        mid = (low + high) // 2
        if(arr[mid] == key):
            return key

        elif(arr[mid] > key):
            return binarySearch(arr, low, mid - 1, key)

        else:
            return binarySearch(arr, mid + 1, high, key)

    else:
        return -1


i = binarySearch(arr, 0, len(arr) - 1, 33)
print(i)
```